# Solving the wave equation with Neumann conditions(?) using Green's functions.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, wave-equation

I either have to solve the wave equation using Green's functions or Fourier transforms. I am given an infinite string which is fixed at $x_0=0$ and at rest for $t<0$. At $t=0$, it receives an instantaneous blow at $x=0$ which imparts an initial velocity $V\delta (x-x_0)$, where V is a constant. Find the position of the string at time t.

Is the initial velocity a Neumann condition? And if so how would I go about solving this as I now have in-homogeneous boundary conditions. Is the wave equation I want to solve homogeneous? I need help picturing how to set this problem up and what the equation is I am actually trying to solve.

Comment: Hint: D'Alembert's formula should apply. All you need to do is set up the problem. Also I believe you mean for $x_0=0$?

Comment: Yes I do mean $x_0=0$ and as I said above, setting up the problem is what I'm currently stuck on.